# Enabling PHP Xdebug remote_enable causing 504 time-out every time

Tags: timeout, xdebug, remote-debugging

I am trying to set up Xdebug correctly. With these settings when I visit any page I get a 504 time-out error after 30+ seconds. (I am using an ssh - tunnel so I use remote_host 127.0.0.1)

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /home/ubuntu/xdebug-cgi.log
xdebug.idekey = "rsalazar"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

Once I was able to get this xdebug log output , for some reason it does not post this output anymore:

```
> Log opened at 2012-03-23 22:13:50 I: Connecting to configured
> address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000. I: Connected to client. :-)
> -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug"
> fileuri="file:///home/ubuntu/www/info.php" language="PHP"
> protocol_version="1.0" appid="3119" idekey="rsalazar"><engine
> version="2.2.0rc1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick
> Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
```

Any idea?

EDIT: I've determined it only happens when I enable debugging on a page (happens always when I turn on 'remote_autostart' of course) ... I want to guess that xdebug is waiting for server to connect (?)

Comment: It's likely that Xdebug and PHP are crashing. Are you sure that this is the only thing you have in your remote log? Or is there more?

Comment: that's all in the log. I started to wonder if PHP is hanging because it's waiting for someone to accept the debug signal, but I am not sure. (Since I have never done php debugging)

Answer (score 2):

Did you open port 9000 in your router? I had had exactly the same problem until I opened the port for inbound and outbound traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I noticed the test php script can bind to the socket at port 9000 as soon as I reload apache with sudo service apache2 reload. That hints that php is not keeping the port open or continuing to listen after apache startups. Will post more if I find something.